# Splitting json data in angular2

Tags: json, angular

I am using angular2 to fetch data from node api. Node api returns data in a format like that

```
{"height":{"low":4,"high":0,"unsigned":true},"currentBlockHash":{"buffer":{"type":"Buffer","data":[8,4,18,32,197,125,99,165,77,70,46,19,215,237,19,57,219,242,168,130,134,153,184,56,68,211,255,62,122,245,216,154,192,254,179,139,26,32,169,218,156,201,73,252,127,198,103,103,43,100,81,90,113,109,163,137,159,156,140,148,125,28,104,79,145,218,72,145,206,6]},"offset":4,"markedOffset":-1,"limit":36,"littleEndian":true,"noAssert":false},"previousBlockHash":{"buffer":{"type":"Buffer","data":[8,4,18,32,197,125,99,165,77,70,46,19,215,237,19,57,219,242,168,130,134,153,184,56,68,211,255,62,122,245,216,154,192,254,179,139,26,32,169,218,156,201,73,252,127,198,103,103,43,100,81,90,113,109,163,137,159,156,140,148,125,28,104,79,145,218,72,145,206,6]},"offset":38,"markedOffset":-1,"limit":70,"littleEndian":true,"noAssert":false}}
```

I only want to display value of `low` in angular2 frontend but problem is I am unable to split that json data into key-value pairs. Either angular2 is displaying whole data or nothing.
This is my component code which receives data in json format

```
import {Component,OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from '~/./../app/app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'dashboard',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.scss'],
  templateUrl: './dashboard.html'
})
export class Dashboard implements OnInit {

  constructor(private AppService: AppService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(){
      this.getStats();
  }

  BlockchainHeight:any;

  getStats(){
      this.AppService.getblockchaininfo().subscribe(data=>{
          console.log(data);
          this.BlockchainHeight=data["_body"];
      });
  }


}
```

And this is my html code which display data

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
   <ba-card>
     <h3> Blockchain Height</h3>
     {{BlockchainHeight}}
   </ba-card>
  </div>
```

Any trick or solution to split that json data into key value pairs?

Comment: Please show the code for `this.AppService.getblockchaininfo()`.

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` returns? What is this `data["_body"]` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure about the specifics regarding Angular2, but this will convert a json string into an object with just plain vanilla javascript

```
var jsonResponse = "{"height":{"low":4,"high":0,"unsigned":true},"currentBlockHash":{"buffer":{"type":"Buffer","data":[8,4,18,32,197,125,99,165,77,70,46,19,215,237,19,57,219,242,168,130,134,153,184,56,68,211,255,62,122,245,216,154,192,254,179,139,26,32,169,218,156,201,73,252,127,198,103,103,43,100,81,90,113,109,163,137,159,156,140,148,125,28,104,79,145,218,72,145,206,6]},"offset":4,"markedOffset":-1,"limit":36,"littleEndian":true,"noAssert":false},"previousBlockHash":{"buffer":{"type":"Buffer","data":[8,4,18,32,197,125,99,165,77,70,46,19,215,237,19,57,219,242,168,130,134,153,184,56,68,211,255,62,122,245,216,154,192,254,179,139,26,32,169,218,156,201,73,252,127,198,103,103,43,100,81,90,113,109,163,137,159,156,140,148,125,28,104,79,145,218,72,145,206,6]},"offset":38,"markedOffset":-1,"limit":70,"littleEndian":true,"noAssert":false}} "; 
var decodedJsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonResponse);
var low = decodedJsonObject.height.low;
```